# How to associate the localhost domain with my application identifier when using Passkey auth?

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, vapor, passkey

Working a Vapor application on localhost, and when trying to authenticate with Passkey using the iPhone simulator, the `authorizationController(controller:didCompleteWithError:)` delegate method triggers this error:

```bash
["NSLocalizedFailureReason": Application with identifier <APP_BUNDLE_ID> is not associated with domain localhost:8080]
```

**The setup on the Vapor project is:**

- The server starts on `https://localhost:8080`
- The `/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` file is being reach through `(Vapor/RouteLoggingMiddleware.swift:14)`.

```json
{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": ["<APP_BUNDLE_ID>"],
        "components": []
      }
    ]
   },
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": ["<APP_BUNDLE_ID>"]
  }
}
```

There is proper communication with the server, as I can see the `username` of the user being received from the iPhone simulator request. The request sends back the `userID` and the `Challenge` to authenticate with Passkey.

**The setup on the iOS project is:**

- Associated Domains is `webcredentials:localhost:8080?mode=developer`

**The code to create the Passkey authentication:**

```swift
  func authenticate(with email: String) async throws {

    let publicKeyProvider = ASAuthorizationPlatformPublicKeyCredentialProvider(
      relyingPartyIdentifier: "localhost:8080"
    )

    // The authentication request to receive the `userID` and `Challenge`.
    // This part is sucessful.
    let authenticationData = AuthenticationData(email: email)
    let urlRequest = try urlRequest(with: authenticationData, atEndpoint: .authentication)
    let data = try await serverCall(for: PublicAuthKeyData.self, on: urlRequest)

    let registrationRequest = publicKeyProvider.createCredentialRegistrationRequest(
      challenge: data.challenge.decodeBase64(),
      name: email,
      userID: data.userID.decodeBase64()
    )

    let authController = ASAuthorizationController(
      authorizationRequests: [registrationRequest]
    )
    authController.delegate = self
    authController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authController.performRequests()
  }
```

From there, the `authorizationController(controller:didCompleteWithError:)` trigger the error `Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1004`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paskeys require verifying the domain with the app via the app sites association file. In order to do this the app needs to be able to make a network request over the internet to get the file so localhost won't work. You can use something like ngrok to expose a local service to the internet to make it work

Comment: Plus if I understand the question and answer correctly... This would cause weird routing issues when testing on device (as localhost on device "doesn't mean anything" given that Passkey testing on a desktop can run both a browser and a server at localhost)

Comment: @0xTim do we then need to change the domain within the entitlements file to the domain generated by ngrok?

Comment: Yes see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77900621/1823705